# How can you use former picture(identicon) as profile picture?

Tags: bug, gravatar

I was messing something with my profile and trying the new hats I've earned and accidentall/out of curiosity I've pressed change picture and then on identicon.

My profile picture have change it became blue with stars, while the previous one was brownish with triangles. I like the former much more, so is there anyway you can retrieve that pricture or change the current one?

Comment: This might be a similar issue as mentioned [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11028/8348).

Comment: @ArthurFischer Any way to retrieve the former gravatar?

Also as I've accidentaly changed my gravatar.

Comment: I cannot say for certain that you have run into the same issue.  But using [this URL](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/39e9fe3f6ea1a59efc14d5bd21c3ccdc?d=identicon&s=128) as the location of a custom image might bring it back.  (The URL is taken from your Area51 profile, actually.)

Comment: I've changed and it looks better, hope it'll last. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a real answer to your question, but I was delighted to find this website a couple of days ago:(if you type your own email you get your identicon)

Edit: removed link since it no longer worked.

Comment: Fun.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It's really nice one. Thanks.

Comment: Oh lol this doesn't even work anymore it sends you to some kpop idol thing